# Command for displaying the logs of celery worker from the server in Docker container?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, celery

I wanted to add celery to my docker file, which I added and when I deployed the changes to the server, I am able to see that celery is doing its job by executing the jobs faster. But, if I want to see the celery worker logs like **"celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info"**, this works in local machine and I am able to see all the logs.
But, in my server, since I am only able to see the logs of the docker container, can anyone guide me or tell me the command by which I can see whether celery is working fine or not in the production phase.

This is my docker-compose file structure:

```
services:
  "name":
    image: "image_name"
    ports:
      - "ports"
    environment:
      - "environment variables"
    networks:
      - "networks"

  celery_worker:
    build:
      context: ./parsers
    command: celery -A parsers worker --loglevel=info
    volumes:
      - ./parsers:/parsers
    depends_on:
      - "image"
```

Now, I want to see the logs of the celery worker too.
Currently, I am able to see the server logs through the command 
**sudo docker logs -f "name"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the answer to my question is:

1. Like I had created a docker file and added celery as a service, so this made a new image of celery in the docker container, and to check the logs of the celery worker, I used the following command  **sudo docker logs -f "Image_name_of_celery"**
2. You can check all the running docker containers and images using the following command: **sudo docker ps**. This will show the results.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that in your build of the `Dockerfile` the `celery` will be symlink from the `celery` log to the `stdout` or `stderr`?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get your question. I don't know much about docker and I am still learning. Please can you elaborate more.